# How do I display all my data on a heatmap

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I am attempting to create a heatmap using code I found on the web. Regardless of me using my own data, or the example code my plots come out with a fraction of the data I input. Please look at the example below.

```
library(gplots)
library(vegan)
df = data.frame(SAMPLE1 = matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=1000),
                SAMPLE2 = matrix(rnorm(20), nrow = 1000),
                SAMPLE3 = matrix(rnorm(20), nrow = 1000))

as.matrix(df) -> mat

#scaleRYG <- colorRampPalette(c("white","light green","green", 
#                               "light blue", "blue", "dark blue",
#                               "purple", "pink", "red"), space = "rgb"#(30)

data.dist <-vegdist(mat, method = "euclidean")

row.clus <-hclust(data.dist, "aver")

heatmap.2(mat, Rowv = as.dendrogram(row.clus), dendrogram = "row", 
          col=redblue(100), margins = c(12, 6), density.info = "none", 
          trace = "none", lhei = c(2,6), colsep = 1:3, sepcolor = "black",
          sepwidth =c(0.001,0.0001), xlab = "Datasets", ylab = "Wikipathways")
```

The image I am getting on Rstudio is similar to below, I am getting less than 100 rows plotted out of a 1000 rows.

[image: Heatmap Examaple]

This is the shareable link if the the upload does not work.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zSjrGUdEtcq8aIhcpTI-2Sd8mRFD1YXn

Is there an issue with the code or the way Rstudio is set up?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What package(s) is/are `vegdist` and `heatmap.2` from? Please include `library` statements at the top of your code. The `scaleRYG` line does not work as is (and simply adding a closing parenthesis doesn't work).

Comment: @ClancyStats I have added the necessary packages and editted the scaleRYG code and heatmap.2 function so it will not be needed now. Thanks

Comment: I ran the code and can't reproduce the error. All 1000 rows are plotted for me.